# react-snap: prevent double load

Tags: vue.js, react-snap

I am using react snap on my VueJS site https://lernzettel.org

However, react-snap introduces a double-first-load of the content, i.e.

1. Pre-rendered version shows up
2. Pre-rendered version vanishes
3. Content is loaded from the CMS & displayed

How can I disable step 2 & 3 for initial page loads.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

-> hydration, see react-snap readme, adjust main.js

Comment: Can you be more specific? I added this to main.js but it shows strange content.

window.snapSaveState = () => {
  document.querySelector("#app").setAttribute("data-server-rendered", "true");
};